# PHP replace patterns in string with URLs

Tags: php, regex, url, square-bracket

I have a few hundred html files that I want to show on a website.
They all have links in them in the following format:

```
[My Test URL|https://www.mywebsite.com/test?param=123]
```

The problem is that some urls are split up so:

```
[My Test URL|https://www.mywebsite.c om/test?param=123]
```

I want to replace all of those with the HTML counter-part so:

```
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/test?param=123">My Test URL</a>
```

I know that with the regex "/[(.*?)]/" I can match the brackets but how can I split by the pipe, remove the whitespaces in the URL and convert everything to a string?

Comment: If you want to match both parts, then add both capture groups (also escaping `[` and `]`) then is just a case of looping over it to output links https://3v4l.org/2Jaid

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works with the given regex. But how can I replace it the text itself? I can't echo the links only but I need to replace everything.

Comment: with [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) https://3v4l.org/9Depu

Comment: Thx a lot:) But then again I have the problem with the whitespaces in the URLs which won't be replaced. Is there a way around that as well?

Comment: oh, lol didn't see the space.. you can use preg_replace_callback to call a function to do stuff on the matches before replace https://3v4l.org/5PbGD - though `https://www.mywebsite.c om/test?param=123` is not a valid domain name, so should fix the issue which is causing it to have spaces, if its hard coded you can do find all and string replace in your editor `mywebsite.c om` -> `mywebsite.com`, shouldn't need code

Comment: or just do `$str = str_replace('mywebsite.c om', 'mywebsite.com', $str);` before you do the regex

Comment: Awesome! Your latest 3v4l works fine! Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I can't replace them because the space is always somewhere else in the URL and the URL is also different every time. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove (white)spaces in the URL part in these markdown links you can use a mere `preg_replace` like

```php
preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\[[^][|]*\|)[^][\s]*\K\s+(?=[^][]*])~', '', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YzP9lg/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[[^][|]*\|)` - end of the previous match or `[`, then zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `|` and then a `|` char
- `[^][\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and whitespace
- `\K` - discard all text matched so far
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[^][]*])` - there must be zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` immediately to the right of the current location.

If you want to remove spaces inside the URL part and convert markdown to HTML, you had better use `preg_replace_callback`:

```php
$text = '[My Test URL|https://ww w.mywebsite.c om/t  est?param=123]';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[([^][|]*)\|([^][]+)]/', function($m) {
    return '<a href="' . str_replace(' ', '', $m[2]) . '">' . $m[1] . '</a>';
}, $text);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/p6skg). *Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][|]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `([^][]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all `WHITESPACES` from a string in `php` all you need to do is:

`$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);`

Where `$string` is your string with the `url`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it for you

```
$html = "[My Test URL|https://www.mywebsite.c om/test?param=123] [My Test URL|https://www.mywebsite.com/test?param=123]";
$html = preg_replace_callback("|\[.*?\|.*?\]|", function($matches){
    list($anchor, $link) = explode("|",substr($matches[0], 1, -1));
    return "<a href='".str_replace(' ', '', $link)."'>$anchor</a>";
}, $html);

echo $html;
// echos  <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/test?param=123">My Test URL</a> <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/test?param=123">My Test URL</a>
```